# Simulate contingency table with known row margins

Tags: python, statistics, sampling

I am trying to simulate a contingency table with known row margins, where the distribution along each column should resemble the distribution of the totals.

The columns X1,X2... are time values which means that neighbours shouldn't be more correlated.

Is there a way to sample this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X1':[None,None,None,None,None],
              'X2':[None,None,None,None,None],
              'X3':[None,None,None,None,None],
              'X4':[None,None,None,None,None],
              'X5':[None,None,None,None,None],
              'total':[80,100,120,40,340]})

df.index = ["A","B","C","D","total"]
df["%"] = [cal_perc(x,340) for x in  df["total"]]
df
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any constraints on the column margins?

Comment: No, it's a general question. I was hoping to get several approaches.